# 500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token (41:5) while using simple jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am learning Express and for template using jade.I have written very simple code but I am getting below error. Please let me know what's the issue.

Error:

> 500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token (41:5)

```
at Parser.pp$4.raise (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2422:15)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:613:10)
at Parser.pp.semicolon (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:590:61)
at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1002:10)
at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:767:22)
at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:655:25)
at Parser.parse (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:525:17)
at Object.parse (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3300:39)
at reallyParse (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn-globals\index.js:22:16)
at findGlobals (H:\NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn-globals\index.js:35:11)
```

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
    body
        div.container
            block content
```

list.jade:

I tried using below code blocks but getting this error in both cases:

---

1. Trial:

---

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    ul
        each flight, index in flights
            - flight = flight.getInformation()
            li= flight.number + ': ' + flight.origin + '-' + flight.destination
```

---

2. Trial:

---

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    ul
    -   each flight in flights
        -   flight= flight.getInformation()
        li= flight.number   +   ':' +   flight.origin   +   '-' +   flight.destination
```

---

`getInformation()` is a method I have written in another module `flight`. Parmeters of `flight` are being passed from js file which calls `list.jade`.

Anyone please help me with this. It seems like there is some syntax error but I am not getting that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I just found the solution to this by digging into the node_modules. for you I would start with the file @ `NodeJS-Lynda\Chap-5\06\start\node_modules\jade\node_modules\with\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js`

```
Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement
```

go to line 1002 and log out the variables at that line, if they don't make any sense continue moving down to the next line in the stack trace towards

```
Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel line 655
```

repeating each log until it gives you something clearer to work with. The pug template will parse everything possible until it 'breaks' and that will give you a very accurate place to look at for your exact problem. **IE** just beyond that last log

Answer (score -1):

Move your `body` in one tab.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
        body
            div.container
                block content
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am using sublime editor.Tried your solution but still getting same error.